# Are React functional components really more lightweight than class components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-component

I've read in [a few places](https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-hooks-migration/) that functional components are more lightweight than class components, and from [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html) it sounds like Facebook intends for functional + hooks to be the preferred paradigm for new components.

The problem I see is that with functional components things like class methods get redefined on every render, instead of just once. Is this not an issue, or do the other advantages of functional components simply outweigh this?

---

**Example for clarity:**

*Class Component*

```
class SignInForm extends React.Component {
  ...
  // Only gets defined when the component is created with `React.createElement`
 submit = () => {
    // send POST request to get an auth token, etc.
  }

  render() {
    <form>
      ...
      <button onClick={this.submit}>Sign In</button>
    </form>
  }
}
```

*Functional Component*

```
function SignInForm (props) {
  ...
  // Gets defined on every render, since this essentially *is* the `render` function
  const submit = () => {
    // send POST request to get an auth token, etc.
  }

  return (
    <form>
      ...
      <button onClick={submit}>Sign In</button>
    </form>
  );
}
```

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Methods defined in the body of the class (in this case usually either lifecycle or callback methods).

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I edited the question to clarify what I mean.

Comment: For a functional (stateless) component, there's no need to call the render function ifs params haven't changed. Classes need to maintain state, so same input is not a guarantee of the same output causing the render function to have to be called more often

Answer (score -2):

`Slowest` part in web apps is the `rendering`. So creating a new function on every render is not a big deal. Also for web apps, `build size` matter and for functional components, minification works better than as it works for class-based components.

With the release of new features like `memo`, `useMemo`, `useCallback` etc. we can get the same performance as we get with class-based components.

React community is moving towards functional components and hooks which is an indication that functional components are not bad.